# What is a0(padded to 32bytes) and 2(padded to 32bytes) in the bytecode?

Tags: etherscan, bytecode

I was exploring about bytecode and came across a sample transaction mentioned in a Medium article. The issue is that I couldn't understand what do the 2 bytecodes mean in the Input Data bytecode below:

The sample tx is here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xac80bab0940f061e184b0dda380d994e6fc14ab5d0c6f689035631c81bfe220b/advanced

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction input data is encoded using [Contract ABI specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html)

```
swapTokensForExactTokens(uint256 amountOut, uint256 amountInMax, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)
```

```
0x
8803dbee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```

- `8803dbee` function signature
- `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001158e460913d00000` amountOut
- `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a4837fc5242c4ec` amountInMax
- `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0` offset to path (dynamic array are encoded using an offset to the array beginning)
- `0000000000000000000000009a7ed54b8c2c5816c1800476f5111a1e88657502` to
- `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060cfee3f` deadline

At offset `0xa0` is the array beginning

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
0000000000000000000000003c9d6c1c73b31c837832c72e04d3152f051fc1a9
```

The first slot is the array length 2, then following are the two entries in the array.